# Poruqe me salta este error?

Tags: javascript, consola

Me sale este error que no entiendo se que sale algo null pero no se que es. Seguro es algo facil pero no le encuentro la vuelta. No se que es lo que encuentra undefined.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
stockproductos.forEach((prod) => {
    const tiendadevidejuegos = document.getElementById("tiendavideojuegos")
    const { id, nombre, precio, desc, img, cantidad} = prod
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerHTML = `
    <div class="producto">
        <div class="card border-info mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="${img}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
            <div class="card-body"> 
                <h5 class="card-title">${nombre}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">${desc}<br> <strong>$${precio}</strong></p>
                <p> Cantidad: ${cantidad} </p>
                <button id="agregar${id}" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar al carrito</button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
    tiendadevidejuegos.appendChild(div)        
    const boton = document.getElementById(`agregar${id}`)           
    boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        agregaralcarrito(id)
    })
})
```

Comment: Puede pasar que no estas seleccionando bien el elemento que supuestamente tiene el id: 'tiendadevideojuegos', revisa eso.

Comment: Haz `console.log(tiendadevidejuegos)`, ¿Qué te sale en consola?... Revisa que esa id esté en el DOM... si no está, ahí el error, saludos.

Comment: El console.log tiene que mostrar undefined. Revisa el codigo html, el id que le pones al elemento posiblemente sea un poco distinto al que pones en el getElementById, por eso te da undefined y posteriormente ese error.

Comment: Hola Agustín, falta un cierre del los div, no creo que sea la fuente del error, pero.. edito la pregunta y lo agrego.

Comment: Ese error suele lanzar cuando no lo encuentra en el DOM, puedes agregar por favor el html donde declaras `tiendavideojuegos`.